# iOS - This is the right process to generate the APNS production certificate?

Tags: ios, certificate, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, production

This is the right process to generate the PRODUCTION certificate?

```
openssl x509 -in aps_development.cer -inform der -out myCert.pem

openssl pkcs12 -nocerts -out myKey.pem -in myCert.p12

cat myCert.pem myKey.pem > my.pem
```

.. and then:

```
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'certificati/my.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, it all looks fine to me.

You can check your production commands against the following good tutorial:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3443/apple-push-notification-services-tutorial-part-12

And your PHP code to connect to the live APNS server appears equally valid. You can compare it against a few good answers here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8249772/766441

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9536457/766441

You may also consider switching the server address to the sandbox APNS server, testing all of your code and then switching the URL to the live server when you are ready to submit the app.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer was very helpful. My last question is on the creation of .pem files.
I'm not sure if the .pem files  are created the same way in both cases (production & development).

Comment: They are created in exactly the same way. ;)