# How do I create a remote push notification on iOS?

Tags: ios, web-services, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am wondering how I may be able to create a remote push notification to send to all the users of my app.

I am currently using the service called "Pushbots" however I am wondering if it would be possible to do by myself without relying on a third party.

I own a hosted domain and I am wondering if it would be possible to send push notifications through that.

Looking forward to your responses.

Thanks.

Comment: The question you're asking will take about 3o mins to answer in detail. In short, store every device's deviceToken in your database and then you can send notifications using your PHP file and Apple's server. In PHP file just loop through all the deviceTokens. see this link for an example of the php file: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535127/send-push-notifications-to-all-users

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading Ray Wenderlich's excellent tutorial on the subject.

http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1